# What's causing this massive white space?

Tags: html, css

URL in question: http://bit.ly/PSWSk5

I'm currently coding on the page above when I noticed that my browser (Chrome) let's me scroll to the right revealing a massive white area that shouldn't be there.

I've looked at the code but can't seem to to see what's causing the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting everything on that page to see if it is wide?

Comment: I have removed the `php` tag and added `html` and `css` as that seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an iframe that has height and width of 1000px.  The iframe's id and name is id="f2655f1b1" name="f2f789918c".

Comment: As an addition: That iframe is absolutely positioned relative to a span located on the right side of the page, increasing the width of the page.

Comment: @jeroen nice catch on the span.